# Automatically Show the Page Number of Atlas QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

How can i show the page number of a atlas on QGIS?

I don't want to use an attribute, i just want to QGIS to automatically show de page number.

I believe that is a simple tool, but i Can find a way to do that.

Answer (score 10):

1. Add a label
2. Set this text:

   [% @atlas_featurenumber %]

Comment: I would suggest : [%'Page '||@atlas_featurenumber   || '/' ||   @atlas_totalfeatures%]

Comment: I have an atlas with multiple pages per feature, how can I number pages in this case?

Comment: compatible qgis 3?

Comment: Yeah works with QGIS 3.